# I didn't understand the proof of the chain rule

Tags: analysis, derivatives

From a lecture note about analysis:

For differentiable functions $f$ and $g$
$$
(g\circ f)'(x_0)=g'(f(x_0))f'(x_0).
$$

Proof: Consider the limit $$\lim_{x \to x_0}{\frac{g(f(x))-g(f(x_0))}{x-x_0}}.$$ Note that $$\lim_{x \to x_0}{\frac{g(f(x))-g(f(x_0))}{x-x_0}}=\lim_{x \to x_0}{\frac{g(f(x))-g(f(x_0))}{f(x)-f(x_0)}\cdot\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}}$$; the second term converges to $f'(x_0)$, while the first term **(since $x-x_0\to 0$ implies $f(x)-f(x_0)\to 0$ by the continuity of $f$)** converges to $$\lim_{x \to x_0}{\frac{g(f(x))-g(f(x_0))}{f(x)-f(x_0)}}=g'(f(x_0)).$$

**Question** Why is the bold sentence necessary? Didn't we already assume that $g$ is differentiable at $f(x_0)$? Why didn't he write "..., while the first term converges to $g'(f(x_0))$ by assumption."?

Comment: My question concerns the first equality: what if $f(x)-f(x_0)=0$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Knowing that $\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)=f(x_0)$ is what is required to say that $$\lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{g(f(x))-g(f(x_0))}{f(x)-f(x_0)}=\lim_{u\to f(x_0)}\frac{g(u)-g(f(x_0))}{u-f(x_0)},$$ which is $g'(f(x_0))$ by differentiability of $g$ at $f(x_0)$.

---

Unfortunately, this proof has a substantial hole in it: the claim $$\frac{g(f(x))-g(f(x_0))}{x-x_0}=\frac{g(f(x))-g(f(x_0))}{f(x)-f(x_0)}\cdot\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}$$ makes sense only when $f(x)-f(x_0)\ne 0.$ If $f$ is a constant function (at least locally, near $x_0$), for example, then this manipulation makes no sense at all (though in that case, we've other recourse). This is why in [this proof](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~ege/131a.1.04s/comp.pdf) of the chain rule, alternate means are taken to bring the $g'(f(x_0))$ analog term in, without risking division by $0$. Does that answer your commented question, or are there particular *steps* in that proof that you don't understand?

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to fix my typo. 
Also, here: http://www.math.ucla.edu/~ege/131a.1.04s/comp.pdf I read that if $f(x)=f(x_0)$ we are in big trouble and then adds several steps to fix it, which I also didn't understand.

Comment: I have added to my answer. Take a look, and let me know if that takes care of things for you.

Comment: "We have that $g(y)-g(f(c))=G_0(y)(y-f(c))$ for $y\not= f(c)$, hence $g(y)-g(f(c))=G(y)(y-f(c))$ even when $y=f(c)$ **(since both sides are zero when $y=f(c)$)**"
Again, the bold part... When I plug in $y=f(c)$ both sides are $0$ in both cases.

Comment: That's exactly what they're saying with the bold part: that plugging in $y=f(c)$ makes both sides $0$, so $$g(y)-g(f(c))=G(y)(y-f(c))$$ when $y=f(c).$ Also, $G(y)=G_0(y)$ for $y\ne f(c),$ so using the fact that $$g(y)-g(f(c))=G_0(y)(y-f(c))$$ for $y\ne f(c),$ it follows that $$g(y)-g(f(c))=G(y)(y-f(c))$$ for ***every*** $y$ in the domain of $g,$ *including* $y=f(c).$

Comment: Yes, but why is this not the case for $g(y)-g(f(c))=G_0(y)(y-f(c))$ when $y=f(c)$? What is the distinction between the two cases?

Comment: Because $G_0(y)$ is *defined* to be $$\frac{g(y)-g(f(c))}{y-f(c)}$$ for all $y$ in the domain of $g,$ **except** for $y=f(c).$ That is, the domain of $G_0$ is the domain of $g,$ with the single point $y=f(c)$ removed. Since $y=f(c)$ isn't in the domain of $G_0,$ then it makes no sense to say that $g(y)-g(f(c))=G_0(y)(y-f(c))$ when $y=f(c)$. After all, what is $G_0(f(c))$? The function $G$ is used as a tool to "fix" $G_0$ and give us the value that we expect $G_0$ to take in its "missing" domain point. It's what allows us to finish the job.

Comment: Now everything is ok. Thank you very much for your patience Cameron :)

Answer (score 2):

To see the necessity of the continuity let's see an example. So let
$$f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}\\
1&\text{if}\ x>0\\
0&\text{if}\ x\leq0
\end{array}\right.$$
then clearly $f$ isn't countinuous at $0$ and let $g(x)=x$ then
$$\lim_{x\to0^+}g(f(x))=g(1)=1\neq0=g(0)=\lim_{x\to0^-}g(f(x))$$
so the limit doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that we want $f(x)-f(x_0)$ to behave like $x-x_0$. The only question is, does it go to 0 like $x-x_0$ does? Because in the definition of the derivative, you need the denominator to go to 0. The denominator only goes to 0 if $f(x)$ goes to $f(x_0)$ as $x$ goes to $x_0$, which is the definition of continuity at $x_0$. So the only way that the limit equals the derivative is if $f$ is continuous there, but that always happens by a previous lemma.

Comment: *The denominator only goes to 0 if $f(x)$ goes to $f(x_0)$ as $x$ goes to $x_0$, which is the definition of continuity at $x_0$*? I think it should be: "The **numerator** goes to $0$ if ..."

Comment: I meant the denominator of the left hand side